# Selenium with Python is not opening the right profile and adding /Default at the end of my selected profile

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I'm trying to automate some tasks with Selenium and I need to interact with certain extensions, so I created a profile that would keep this extensions.

Since Chrome's new update, my script stopped working because it wasn't opening the right profile anymore.

My code:

```
def open_browser():

    optionsinput = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    optionsinput.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/User1/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 13")

    # Open the browser
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = optionsinput) 
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

    return driver
```

When I try to open the extension, I find that the extension is not installed in the profile and I get this:

[image: chrome message]

and further investigation by opening `chrome://version/` shows that it's adding `/Default` to the user path:

```
Profile Path    /Users/User1/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 13/Default
```

I'm out of ideas on how to fix it... I've created new profiles, tried to create a default folder within the profile that would hold the extension... nothing.